# Android RecyclerView mixes up data when scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have looked at countless stackoverflow threads about this but could not find a solution. So my problem is when i'm scrolling trough my recycler view the data gets mixed up for a split second and then it gets corrected again.

Here is my adapter:

```
class ListViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Typeface font;
private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> events;
private VisitorAttendeesHandler visitorAttendeesHandler;

ListViewAdapter(Typeface font, Context context, ArrayList<String> events) {
    this.font = font;
    this.context = context;
    this.events = events;
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;
    FrameLayout progressBar;
    TextView event_title, event_date, event_time, event_address;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        progressBar = (FrameLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        event_title = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.event_title);
        event_date = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.event_date);
        event_time = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.event_time);
        event_address = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.event_address);
    }

    void showProgressBar() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    void hideProgressBar() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    void setClickListener(final String eid) {
        mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, EventInfoActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("eid", eid);
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

    public void setAttendees(String eid) {
        final ArrayList<User> attendeesList = new ArrayList<>();
        final TextView event_attendees = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.event_attendees);
        final ImageView statusBadge = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.statusBadge);
        event_attendees.setTypeface(font);

        visitorAttendeesHandler = new VisitorAttendeesHandler(eid, LoggedInUser.getInstance().getUid(), new VisitorAttendeesCallback() {
            @Override
            public void attendeeEventStatus(AttendeeStatus status) {
                if (attendeesList.isEmpty()) event_attendees.setText("0");
                Log.e("STATUS - ", status.toString());
                switch (status) {
                    case APPROVED:
                        statusBadge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        statusBadge.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.joined_badge));
                        break;
                    case REJECTED:
                        statusBadge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        statusBadge.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rejected_badge));
                        break;
                    case PENDING:
                        statusBadge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        statusBadge.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pending_badge));
                        break;
                    default:
                        statusBadge.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpdate(Map<String, AttendeeStatus> attendees, final AttendeesCallbackEvent trigger) {
                for (Map.Entry e : attendees.entrySet()) {
                    if (e.getValue() == AttendeeStatus.APPROVED) {
                        CurrentUserListeners.getUserInfo(e.getKey().toString(), new UserFetchedCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void ready(User user) {
                                if (trigger == AttendeesCallbackEvent.ADDED) {
                                    attendeesList.add(user);
                                    event_attendees.setText(Integer.toString(attendeesList.size()));
                                } else if (trigger == AttendeesCallbackEvent.REMOVED) {
                                    attendeesList.remove(user);
                                    event_attendees.setText(Integer.toString(attendeesList.size()));
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

                visitorAttendeesHandler.getAttendeeStatus();
            }
        });

        visitorAttendeesHandler.subscribeToApprovedAttendees();
        visitorAttendeesHandler.getAttendeeStatus();

    }

    public void setImage(String eid) {
        final SimpleDraweeView draweeView = (SimpleDraweeView) mView.findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

        if (!eid.equals("")) {
            EventPictureDao eventPictureDao = new EventPictureDaoImpl(eid);
            eventPictureDao.getEventPhotos(new PhotosFetchedCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPhotosReady(HashMap<String, String> photoURLs) {
                    if (photoURLs != null) {
                        GenericDraweeHierarchyBuilder builder =
                                new GenericDraweeHierarchyBuilder(context.getResources());
                        GenericDraweeHierarchy hierarchy = builder
                                .setFadeDuration(300)
                                .setPlaceholderImage(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.no_photo_placeholder))
                                .setPlaceholderImageScaleType(ScalingUtils.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP)
                                .setActualImageScaleType(ScalingUtils.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP)
                                .build();
                        draweeView.setHierarchy(hierarchy);

                        for (Map.Entry e : photoURLs.entrySet()) {
                            draweeView.setImageURI(e.getValue().toString());
                        }

                    } else {
                        draweeView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_photo_placeholder);
                        draweeView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_list_view, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(itemView);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    //holder.showProgressBar();
    EventDao eventDao = new EventDaoImpl();
    eventDao.getEventInfo(events.get(position), new EventFetchedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onEventReady(Event event) {
            holder.event_title.setText(event.getEventTitle());
            holder.event_date.setText(event.getStartDate());
            holder.event_time.setText(event.getStartTime());
            holder.setAttendees(events.get(position));
            holder.event_address.setText(event.getEventAddress());
            holder.setImage(events.get(position));
            holder.setClickListener(events.get(position));
            holder.hideProgressBar();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onDetachedFromRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    visitorAttendeesHandler.detachAllListeners();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return events.size();
}
```

Can someone explain my why is this happening and what is the proper way to implement a recycler view loading async data? Thanks.

Comment: I noticed you don't have any calls to `notifyDataSetChanged` or any adapter notify* method.  I think that has something to do with it.

Comment: Don't create a new Instance each time inside onBindViewHolder. You create it once and from the next times, you just use notifyDataSetChanged() method! It won't hamper the UI or anything!

Answer (score 2):

This may not be your solution, but you should **never** put the int position parameter as final in the onBindViewHolder (`final int position`), because there are states of the recycler view where the position on the adapter doesn't match with the position on the layout manager. Instead if you want to access the position, use this method: `holder.getAdapterPosition()`

Comment: @HamzaAbdullah sorry about that. You can read the official documentation where they explain a little bit more and recommend the same method I mentioned above: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getadapterposition